# setup alarm in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to work with `AlarmManager` in android. I have the following code which should set the alarm for 3 secs from when the button was clicked. I do not receive any errors but the code in my `AlarmReceiver` is never triggered.

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.context = this;
        Button setAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("MAIN", "SETTING ALARM");
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000, pi);
                Log.i("MAIN", "ALARM SET");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("ALARM RECEIVER", "ALARM RECEIVED");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.alarm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I see the alarm set output in my logcat so I know its getting past the point where I actually set my alarm, but my alarm receiver never gets called. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This may just be a typo in your question, but your manifest is registering a receiver with the name `AlarmReciever`, which is misspelled. I would expect there to be compile-time or runtime errors, though.

Comment: @cybersam that was it -_-, thanks a lot, funny that I didn't receive any error